# Is possible \footnote{} inside PsTricks/Psmatrix?

Tags: pstricks, footnotes, psmatrix

Is possible inserting "\footnote{This is a footnote you can see in the lower side}" in a graph with Pstricks Psmatrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\footnotemark` at the place of the footnote, and `\footnotetext{This is a footnote you can see in the lower side.}` just after the PStricks picture.